# Why girls are discouraged to attend in Salatul Eid?

Tags: salat, women, islamic-basis, eid

Assalamualaikum.

In the Indian subcontinent, girls/women are discouraged to attend in Salatul Eid? I don't know about the other parts of the world.

However, is there any reason behind it?

Jajakallah

Comment: It's cultural bias.  The Prophet encouraged women to attend eid al adha prayerS.

Comment: @Sayyid, what about Eid al fitr? is there any matter regarding parda (covering)?

Answer (score 1):

Aslaam ,
According to the sahih hadith we are encouraged to allow women attend the eid Salaah so long as they are veiled.

This might be a custom (cultural) of the Subcontinent to keep women away but does not follow with the sunnah. It might also be to prevent fitnah and the protection of both the women and men from Zina and nuffs.

Hadith : 
Narrated by al-Bukhaari, 1/93; Muslim, 890. According to another report: “We were commanded to come out and to bring out the adolescent girls and those in seclusion.”

According to a report narrated by al-Tirmidhi: The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) used to bring out the virgins, adolescent girls, women in seclusion and menstruating women on the two Eids, but the menstruating women were to keep away from the prayer place and witness the gathering of the Muslims. One of them said, “O Messenger of Allaah, what if she does not have a jilbaab?” He said, “Then let her sister lend her one of her jilbaabs.” (Agreed upon).

According to a report narrated by al-Nasaa’i, Hafsah bint Sireen said: Umm ‘Atiyyah hardly ever mentioned the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) but she would say, “May my father be sacrificed for him.” I said, “Did you hear the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) say such and such,” and she said, “Yes, may my father be sacrificed for him, and he said, ‘Let the adolescent girls, women in seclusion and menstruating women come out to attend Eid and witness the gathering of the Muslims, but let the menstruating women avoid the prayer place.’” Narrated by al-Bukhaari, 1/84

InshaAllah this helps to answer you question.

Answer (score 0):

> However, is there any reason behind it?

It is mostly an opinion of some (whom are the minority) not backed by anything from the Quran nor Sunnah. Their reasoning is mostly what bad can come out of it (which if you think of it, many things can turn into bad, doesn't make it wrong).

I did take a look at the [link](http://www.askimam.org/public/question_detail/14924) you commented on another answer and it seems like that opinion was not backed by any hadith.

Comment: They had given reference in bracket. Rare references have specific references and in case of most prominent references they did not give specific references. May be they assumed that those who are practicing  would easily get the indicated ahadis.